# Sorting nodes in XML

Tags: java, xml

how to do the sorting of xml elements in an xml
for example 
input xml is like this 
Person 
  A
  B
Employee
  A
  B
Person
  C
  D
Employee
  C
  D

Now i want to sort the xml to like 
output 
Person 
  A
  B
Person
  C
  D
Employee
  A
  B
Employee
  C
  D

That is all nodes starting with Person should come first then Employye nodes...

Am trying like this now ,

```
BufferedReader docInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
BufferedWriter docOutput = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));
StringBuffer insb = new StringBuffer();

String line = "", segment="";
String beginSegment = "";

Vector a=new Vector();
Vector b=new Vector();

Properties prop = System.getProperties();
String lineSeparator = prop.getProperty("line.separator");

int start=0,pos=0;

try
{
    while ((line = docInput.readLine()) != null)
    {
       line.replace(lineSeparator,"");      
       insb.append(line);
    }

    pos=insb.indexOf(":Recipient");
    pos=pos-15;
    pos=insb.indexOf("<",pos);
    beginSegment=insb.substring(0,pos);             
    System.out.println(" Begin "+beginSegment);
    insb=insb.replace(0,pos,"");

    while(insb.indexOf("Recipient>")>0)
    {
        pos=insb.indexOf("Recipient>");
        segment=insb.substring(0,pos+10);
        a.add(segment);
        segment="";
        insb=insb.replace(0,pos+10,"");
    }

    for(int y=0;y<b.size();y++)
        if(b.get(y).toString().contains("Employee>"))
        {
            a.add(b.get(y).toString());
            b.remove(y);
        }

    for(int y=0;y<a.size();y++)
        b.add(a.get(y).toString());

    b.add(0,beginSegment);
    b.add(insb.toString());

    for(int y=0;y<b.size();y++)
        docOutput.write(b.get(y).toString());

    docOutput.close();
    docInput.close();
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using an XML parser?

Comment: you mean to say domparser

Comment: or sax parser...  or stax parser...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer to the compareTo method?

```
public int compareTo(String anotherString)
```

Compares two strings lexicographically. The result is a positive integer if this String object lexicographically follows the argument string. The result is zero if the strings are equal; compareTo returns 0 exactly when the equals(Object) method would return true.

Anyway, you should use an XML Parser. This way, if you expand object-relational mapping functionality, I mean if you get an instance of a Person or an Employee, you could also implement Comparable in these class to sort as you like your People